# Why couldn't Melkor return from the void after the War of Wrath?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

[Melkor](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Melkor) came back from the void (above the Walls of Night) after he was expelled by [Tulkas](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Tulkas) during the First Battle of All, and destroyed the [Two Lamps](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Two_Lamps).  After that, he was again defeated in the Battle of Powers and locked in the Halls of Mandos.

My question is: why didn't he do it again, as he does when he's body was killed by the [Host of Valinor](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/The_Host_of_Valinor) in the [War of Wrath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_Wrath)?

Comment: The Term Wall Of Things Its just a bad translation from a compatriot brazilian guy,he translated it from the original translations into Portuguese and converted to english again,its supposed to be:Wall Of The World

Comment: it is said that only the Valar know how far extends ekkaia the ocean before things.He could be on the beginning Of Ekkaia

Comment: After SO MUCH research i found that Morgoth not been in the void

Comment: The Walls Of NIgth is in fact a mountain,and magical transparent ice it was

Comment: @user23291: I'm not sure about that.  [Here's the source](http://andrewcm.deviantart.com/art/Morgoth-Bauglir-348909296); I see no mention of reuse restrictions on the page.  Even if there are none, it seems rude to use the picture without linking to said source.

Comment: Morgoth may have been in a piece of land or water, in the beginning of ekkaia,before the Walls of Night,almost out of the atmosphere of Arda(after being expelled by Tulkas,during The First Battle Of All),then you can say that him was verging so much on the finish Of The World, it was like he was almost out of it

Comment: SO THE DEFINITIVE ANSWER IS:Melkor Only been in the void(After him arrived in Arda),after the War Of Wrath,for having been expelled(none Valar could back to the void when arrived in Arda by himself),then he does not know how to get back.When He was looking for the Imperishable Flame ,before Arda,he could return to the place of Eru(of course he was looking for this without the knowledge of Eru)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT:

I understand your confusion now. In Chapter 1 it is written that Melkor "passed therefore over the Walls of the Night with his host, and came to Middle-earth far in the north;". This, however, isn't the same Door of Night that seperated Arda from the Void, but rather a great mountain range that surrounded the land masses of Arda in the beginning. Melkor wasn't lurking in the Void, but in the uncharted wastes in the northern edges of the world. You can see from passages in the Silmarillion that the Door of Night was set in the "Walls of the World", at the "outermost rim of the world", and that you have to pass through Valinor to get there (Silmarillion, ch.24), whereas the Walls of the Night encircle the world, so that Melkor can pass over them and come to the North of Middle Earth (*ibid*, ch.1).

In the comments, you've brought a quote which seems to muddle the issue even further, referencing The Wall of Things and the Door of Night, but these are part of earlier drafts of the History of Middle Earth, and were revised and have not made it into the Silmarillion itself. The term "Wall of Things" does not appear in the Silmarillion at all.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

After the Battle of the Powers, Melkor wasn't expelled from Arda:

> and he was cast into prison in the fastness of Mandos, whence none can escape, neither Vala, nor Elf, nor mortal Man. Vast and strong are those halls, and they were built in the west of the land of Aman.

(Silmarillion, p.60, Unwin Paperback edition, 1983).

So Melkor wasn't cast out after the Battle of the Powers, merely chained with Angainor and left to rot in the Halls of Mandos. And afterwards allowed to roam Valinor. It is only after the War of Wrath at the end of the First Age that he is cast beyond the Doors of Night, something that is considered irreversible.

It's interesting to note, though, that in some earlier versions of the story, Melkor *does* come back from the Void, at the very end of time. And a host of heroes from throughout history [confronts him and his hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagor_Dagorath), and Turin Turambar fells the great dragon Ancalagon that leads the charge. Of course, this doesn't mesh well with some other concepts, such as that Men don't really wait around for eternity like Elves do, so that's probably one reason it was scrapped.

Comment: I Found THIS that contradicts what you say Avner. The Walls of the Night were the outer walls of the world beyond Ekkaia that surrounded Arda as its boundaries in the Elder Days. In the North and South, Ekkaia was narrower and the Walls were closer to the north and south lands of Arda. During the time of the Lamps of the Valar, Melkor came from the Void over the Walls of Night into the north of Arda, and secretly built Utumno. About the World are the Ilurambar, or Walls of the World. They are as ice and glass and steel, being above all the imagination of the Children of Earth cold, transparent

Comment: And i found that Doors of Night(watched by earendil and Mandos after the Battle Of Wrath)is a part of the Walls Of The Night,I found it in the book,AND its important JUT that:The Walls Of Night Did Separete Arda Of The Void,AND Melkor DID COME FROM THE VOID After The First Battle Of All(ALL INFORMATION PULLOUT OF THE BOOK)

Comment: @user23291 Please provide a reference to the location in the book where you found it, so I can either refute it, or concede and change my answer.

Comment: ''So came Tulkas the Strong,whose anger passes like a mighty wind, scattering cloud and darkness before it; and Melkor fled before his wrath and his laughter, and forsook Arda, and there was peace for a long age.''Chapter One

Comment: ''Therefore he gathered to himself spirits out of the halls
of Ea that he had perverted to his service, and he deemed himself strong.And seeing now his time he drew near again to Arda, and looked down upon it, and the beauty of the Earth in its Spring filled him the more with''Chapter One

Comment: ''The Walls of the Night were the outer walls of the world beyond Ekkaia that surrounded Arda as its boundaries in the Elder Days.''i do not know what chapter

Comment: ''Thus came it that the Gods dared a very great deed, the most mighty of their works; for making a fleet of magic rafts and boats with Ulmo's aid - and otherwise had none of these endured to sail upon the waters of Vai - they drew to the Wall of Things, and there they made the Door of Night.'' i do not know what chapter too

Comment: ''...Of The Earth in its Spring filled hime more with HATE...''(couldn't edit)

Comment: I've updated the question in order to reflect your latest quotes.

Comment: I think you have confused The Walls Of Night between The Walls Of Sun,because the Walls Of Sun Indeed were mountains

Comment: Its Strange Melkor have gone to the void Expelled by Tulkas,when is said that none Valar could back to the void when arrived in Arda